# Android - Transparent Overlay Activity that accepts button presses

Tags: android, overlay, transparent

Is it possible to have a transparent activity running that will accept button presses? I need to allow touches through, but capture the hardware volume buttons (in onButtonPressed).

Any pointers? Thank you

Comment: what do you want, give some example...?

Comment: i want to remap the volume buttons in other actives. I was thinking that b/c a service cannot accept hardware button events, i can have a transparent activity that will catch the volume presses and remap them how i want (by returning true so the system doesnt deal with it)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can have a transparent activity, but you can have transparent buttons.

Comment: you can have transparent activities. i've done that part. the problem is if i allow touches through then i lose control of the hardware keys...

Comment: Oh i misunderstood.  I still do not entirely understand, but I know you can @Override
 public void onBackPressed()    Maybe it would work for volume buttons too.

Comment: it doesnt. b/c the system isn't passing those calls to my activity. that is the crux of the problem

Comment: I am sorry but I still do not understand the question.  Perhaps some code may help.